# Linux kernel sendpage function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Suppose I have a user space allocated buffer and I want to use sendpage() to send it through NIC.

sendpage supports a zerocopy operation. the following will happen:
1. get_page - increase reference count
2. send the page through NIC and receive ACK
3. put_page

Is it possible that the pages can be freed or resused before the sendpage actually completes.

(Considering TCP protocol)

Answer (score 1):

you need to take care of few things like:

1) user pages need to be pinned in memory: depending on OS environment there are various ways to pin it, use OS supplied APIs to pin it

2) free won't happen if reference count on page > 0, but you need to make sure no one else is decremented ref count on page

3) nfs code in linux uses uses sendpage mechanism, so that's a good place to check for your reference.

cheers, cforfun!